# Why does Keras Tensorboard scalar graph not linear (loop)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

I'm using TensorBoard via Keras. But scalar graph is messed up. As in not linear and looping back to itself. Is there anyway to correct this?

[image]

```
class LRTensorBoard(TensorBoard):
    def __init__(self, log_dir):
        super().__init__(log_dir=log_dir)
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        logs.update({'lr': K.eval(self.model.optimizer.lr)})
        super().on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)

model = Sequential()
model.add(GRU(16, input_shape=(TimeStep.TIME_STEP + 1, TimeStep.FEATURES), activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(GRU(16, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(GRU(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir=logDir, histogram_freq=0, write_graph=True)
tensorboard.set_model(model)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimize, metrics=[categorical_accuracy])
history = model.fit(TimeStep.fodder, TimeStep.target, epochs=100, shuffle=True, batch_size=4064, validation_split=0.3, callbacks=[tensorboard, LRTensorBoard(log_dir=logDir)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because TensorBoard expects all logs to have a different directory. For example, if you have 2 models named CNN1 and CNN2, then you should have the following structure:

```
logs/
    CNN1/
    CNN2/
```

If you do not have this exact structure, TensorBoard will consider that both logs belong to the same training session, hence the weird curves...

[EDIT] When I read your code, I see one easy fix: when you specify the logdir, append a directory with a timestamp as suffix